# is it correct to use OnPropertyChanged event to ask application to do something?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

My MVVM application contains two views:

- AllStrategiesView
- StrategyView

When user click certain strategy in AllStrategiesView StrategyView with this strategy is created. I use such code to notify application that StrategyView should be created:

```
    .............
    public void OpenStrategyView()
    {
        OnPropertyChanged("OpenStrategy");
    }
    .................
    private void OnWorkspacePropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        const string openStrategyString = "OpenStrategy";
        if (e.PropertyName == openStrategyString)
        {
            AllStrategiesViewModel vm = (sender as AllStrategiesViewModel);
            OpenStrategy(vm.SelectedStrategy);
        }
    }
```

However another part of the program shows error message because there are no such property "OpenStrategy":

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Warns the developer if this object does not have
    /// a public property with the specified name. This 
    /// method does not exist in a Release build.
    /// </summary>
    [Conditional("DEBUG")]
    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    public void VerifyPropertyName(string propertyName)
    {
        // Verify that the property name matches a real,  
        // public, instance property on this object.
        if (TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this)[propertyName] == null)
        {
            string msg = "Invalid property name: " + propertyName;

            if (this.ThrowOnInvalidPropertyName)
                throw new Exception(msg);
            else
                Debug.Fail(msg);
        }
```

The question is:

Is it right or wrong to use `OnPropertyChanged` to notify application that something need to be done? Should I rewrite my code to not to use `OnPropertyChanged` or should I disable `VerifyPropertyName` code?

Comment: I am not an MVVM expert but I agree with devdigital.   PropertyChanged is designed to be used with Public Properties.   If I have a calculated Public Property then I will call Notify.. on the calculated property when the value of an input changes.

Answer (score 0):

This is bad practice. The `PropertyChanged` event on `INotifyPropertyChanged` should be used to notify subscribers that a property on the object instance has changed. This is typically used in WPF to notify the UI that it needs to update itself with the new property value.

In MVVM, you should use some kind of commanding or alternative viewmodel/view communication mechanism to invoke verbs (methods) on your view model from the view. The commanding provided by WPF has limitations, so I would recommend using an [MVVM framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4913946/looking-for-the-wpf-mvvm-framework) and the mechanisms that they provide.

Answer (score 0):

Well it depends on what you want it to do.  In your case it looks like you have a property "Workspace" which indicates which VM you should be looking at.  This doesn't seem too bad of a usage IMHO.

If you were doing something completely unrelated to the property that was changed then it might work, but it's certainly not what I'd expect it to do (see [Principle of Least Astonishment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment)).  OnPropertyChanged is intended to indicate that a property that has been bound to has changed and should be re-fetched.

You can of course just have another event on your ViewModel, like:

```
public event Action<String> OpenStrategy;
```

One more thing...  This code is completely redundant:

```
const string openStrategyString = "OpenStrategy";
if (e.PropertyName == openStrategyString)
```

the following is exactly the same, from the compiler's perspective, and much more readable:

```
if (e.PropertyName == "OpenStrategy")
```

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong in asking your application to do something in the `PropertyChanged` event, however do not raise a `PropertyChanged` event just to ask the application to do something.

`PropertyChanged` is used to indicate that a property has changed, and should be used for that only.

[Devdigital's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9398711/302677) gives a good example, that the UI uses the `PropertyChange` notification to know when it should update. Other objects can also subscribe to receive change notifications, and they should only be notified when a value changes, not when you want to run some application code.

Using your example, I would rewrite it like this:

```
public void OpenStrategyView()
{
    OpenStrategy(this.SelectedStrategy);
}

private void OnWorkspacePropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == "SelectedStrategy")
    {
        OpenStrategyView();
    }
}
```

Comment: `OnWorkspacePropertyChanged` is called when Property is changed so you still call `OpenStrategyView()` when `e.PropertyName == "OpenStrategy"` so you still use `PropertyChange` :)

Comment: @javapowered I am not sure I understand what you're saying, however I did just realize that you had a method name in the `PropertyChange` notification. Since the `PropertyChanged` event should never get called with a method name, I altered the code sample so it uses a Property name and not a Method name.