# Is firing PropertyChanged from a different property considered bad practice?

Tags: xaml

Apologies if there is a similar question, I couldn't see one from my search. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9398665/is-it-correct-to-use-onpropertychanged-event-to-ask-application-to-do-something) seems similar but not close enough.

Anyway, as in the title I'm just wanting to make sure what I'm doing isn't considered bad practice, or that there isn't a better way as how I'm working now doesn't feel quite right (I'm pretty new at data binding).

Anyway, on to the code:

So I have a few properties my XAML is bound to, and I want to XAML to update when the properties change. The problem is I'd prefer properties I don't set directly, but ones that calculate their values. So is this a good/legitimate way of accomplishing that?

```
    public IPolicy Policy
    {
        get { return _policy; }
        set
        {
            _policy = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("HasAdminFee");
            OnPropertyChanged("AdminFeeMessage");
        }
    }
    public bool HasAdminFee
    {
        get { return Policy != null && Policy.ChargeAdminFeesValue > 0; }
    }
    public string AdminFeeMessage
    {
        get { return HasAdminFee ? string.Format(HasAdminFeeMessage, PolicyFact.ChargeAdminFeesValue) : NoAdminFeeMessage; }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing this the right way.  I think it's an effective and acceptable practice.  On the WPF apps that I'm currently working on, we use this method.